# аномальные 4px в дочернем элементе

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Объясните пожалуйста происхождение этих
четырех пикселей в "div.col-6"

[image: скриншот из Chrome_DevTools]

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
CSS

.grid {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display:flex;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для img пропиши `display: block;`
Проблема в том, что элементы типа inline, inline-block воспринимаются системой как текст. Это значит, что картинка является как бы одним символом в тексте. Есть определенное количество символов, для которых необходим дополнительный пробел внизу для того, что нарисовать хвостик, закорлючку и т.п. Это относится к таким символам как: "р", "у" и т.п.
Чтобы исправить данную ситуацию мы просто меняем тип объекта и все должно решиться.

Comment: либо `.col-6 { font-size: 0; }` (хотя лучше обернуть во что-то, и этому чему-то уже свойство, ибо для сетки указывать размер шрифта не особо хорошо)